# How to search a directory/directories in unix by excluding certain file extensions

Tags: unix, grep, find, ls

I've tried using

```
find . | grep -v '(.ext1|.ext2)$'
```

But it still returns those files ending with extensions `.ext1` and `.ext2`. Then I tried the following:

```
ls | grep -v ".ext1$" | grep -v ".ext2$"
```

and this works how I want it. Is there another way to do what I'm looking for ? All I want to do is list all files or directories that do NOT end in `.ext1` or `.ext2`.

Comment: `.` is not escaped ... escape it and both should work

Comment: What are you excluding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not escaped the `.` try this . It will work. Remember `.` needs to be escaped.

```
ls | grep -v '\.ext1$' | grep -v '\.ext2$'
```

same for your `find`

```
find . | grep -v '(\.ext1|\.ext2)$'
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The double `grep` will work, but is not optimal (compared with `grep -E` or `egrep`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes it won't be as fast ..you are right ... it will take more time .. however the OP had specifically asked in another response about what was wrong with his code. That is why I have made it that way. I am sure from the `find` example he will understand it.

Comment: I do understand. I liked this answer the best because it explained what i did wrong in my examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with `find`:

```
find . \! -name \*.ext1 \! -name \*.ext2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
ls | grep "[^(\.ext1|\.ext2)]$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extended regular expression (ERE) which requires `grep -E` or `egrep`:

```
find . | grep -E -v '\.(ext1|ext2)$'
find . | egrep   -v '\.(ext1|ext2)$'
```

I've also escaped the `.` so it is not treated as a metacharacter.

As you wrote it (`grep -v '(.ext1|.ext2)$'`) the parentheses and pipe are not metacharacters (but `.` and `$` are), so the command would eliminate names such as:

```
(Xext1|Yext2)
function(Aext1|Bext2)
```

Where the parentheses and pipe are literally a part of the file name.